# Synchronize Git repository across devices?

Tags: git, synchronization

Is it possible to keep a large number of small Git repositories synchronized across multiple devices in a manner, that keeps also uncommitted changes synchronized?

Currently, for various small scripts and Emacs customizations, I am using git repositories that reside in my Dropbox account. For the most part this works well, but occassionally I close the PC before all blobs have been uploaded, and will find that I can't work with the repository on the other PC, until I ensure that the first PC finishes uploading -- an issue, since they are one hour by public transport apart.

Relying on Github for synchronization doesn't work well for me:

- I am more likely to forget the `push` than Dropbox is not to complete.
- I don't think there is a way to propagate `git branch -d` across devices.
- Some of the files are configuration files, so I'd like both PCs to automatically check out the most current state. With Dropbox this happens implicitly, with git I'd have to run `git pull` on all repositories.

Comment: What about rsync?

Comment: @CodeWizard Rsync doesn't do bidirectional synchronization, and requires the remote PC to be connected. It is a laptop, so usually it is on standby when I am at work.

Answer (score 0):

This trouble has nothing to do with Git. It is matter of the workflow.

I see two reasonable options:

1. Do not turn off the computer and make sure you have remote access to it. Optionally, you could use wake-on-lan or something like that to be more energy efficient.
2. Delay the shutdown until the sync is complete. It can be done automatically but it depends on your setup.

Comment: The remote PC is a private laptop, so the options are somewhat limited.